# Python - How to put tuples into a single list?

Tags: python, tuples

I have variables of tuples:

```
student1 = ("Allan", "Anderson")
student2 = ("Barry", "Byars")
brendan = ("Brendan","Smith")
sandy = ("Sandy","Garner")
```

I want to put them in a list:

```
students = [("Allan", "Anderson"),("Barry", "Byars")]
```

How would you do this? I have 7 variables of tuples and is there an efficient way to do this?

I know students.append() can do it but because I have 7 variables, is there a faster way?

Comment: Do you have any convention for your variables? all of them start with `student` prefix?

Comment: some starts with the first names e.g. brendan = ('brendan', 'smith')

Answer (score 8):

You should use a better data structure here (like a dictionary) :

```
Students = {
    "student1": ("Allan", "Anderson"),
    "student2": ("Barry", "Byars"),
    "brendan": ("Brendan", "Smith"),
    "sandy": ("Sandy", "Garner")
}

StudentList = [student for student in Students.values()]
print(StudentList)
```

Output

```
[('Allan', 'Anderson'), ('Barry', 'Byars'), ('Brendan', 'Smith'), ('Sandy', 'Garner')]
```

In this way, if you want to add another list you just have to add a single line in your dictionary without changing any logic :

```
Students["JohnDoe"] = ("John", "Doe")
```

Output :

```
[('Allan', 'Anderson'), ('Barry', 'Byars'), ('Brendan', 'Smith'), ('Sandy', 'Garner'), ('John', 'Doe')]
```

Answer (score 4):

If there's no structure to your variable names, this is the easiest way.

```py
students = [student1, student2, brendan, sandy]
```

```
[('Allan', 'Anderson'), ('Barry', 'Byars'), ('Brendan', 'Smith'), ('Sandy', 'Garner')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your variables as a dictionary where the keys are the names of the variables.

For example:

```
vars_dict = {
"student1": ("Allan", "Anderson"),
"student2": ("Barry", "Byars")
}
```

and then using dict's `values()` method get all values as a list:

```
students = list(vars_dict.values())
```

Answer (score -1):

The simple way to achieve this can be,

```
student1 = ("Allan", "Anderson")
student2 = ("Barry", "Byars")
student = [student1, student2]

print(student)
```